# ios:EXC_BAD_ACCESS for Webview delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, crash-reports, crashlytics

I have a situation where I am trying to resolve these Crashlytics issues and I have this crash log

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x34217f46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x29a2d5a3 -[UIWebView webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 182
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2630cad4 __invoking___ + 68
3  CoreFoundation                 0x26239645 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2623d0c7 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 50
5  WebKitLegacy                   0x326d9261 -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 224
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2630b62f ___forwarding___ + 354
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2623d008 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
8  CoreFoundation                 0x2630cad4 __invoking___ + 68
9  CoreFoundation                 0x26239645 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 300
10 WebCore                        0x31c02729 HandleDelegateSource(void*) + 100
11 CoreFoundation                 0x262cefbf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
12 CoreFoundation                 0x262ce461 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 364
13 CoreFoundation                 0x262cca35 __CFRunLoopRun + 772
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2621a3b1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2621a1c3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16 GraphicsServices               0x2d801201 GSEventRunModal + 136
17 UIKit                          0x2988443d UIApplicationMain + 1440
18 abc                          0x0030dcd7 main (main.m:14)
```

I can understand that its some callback on webview delegate and bad excess has occurred, so to rectify this I handled the delegates via

```
[self.webview stopLoading];
self.webview.delegate =nil;
```

in all the classes, yet I can see this crash. Can you enlighten me what's possibly going wrong and some approach to rectify this?

Comment: Hello @AnkitSachan, In which line you phase this issue? have you debug all the code with break point in your class?

Comment: @ParasJoshi I am getting these crash logs from crashlytics and there are many webviews in code base thus I am not able to actually debug rather I verified the code did a dry run and everything seems working fine

Comment: Ankit please explain more about your issue..many web views means ?

Comment: Please provide more information and if necessary also code, to give us a chance to understand whats going wrong here.

Comment: @Hi All: as I have stated in the question I am looking for the approach or methodology to handle such scenario where I have just these crash logs and nothing else moreover web views are widely distributed over the code base and I am not sure which one is causing the issue

Comment: It seems odd that the stack trace contains `decidePolicyForNavigationAction`. That belongs to the `WebPolicyDelegate` which is not supported on iOS. Its OSX only. Any chance you have linked in a library that has been built with OSX headers? This would explain the crash since NSInvolcation is probably calling something which does not exist. So my hunch would be  it relates to some 3rd party code you have linked in.

Comment: You are not giving us much information to go on other than a stack trace. Is this on iPhones, iPads or both and what are you doing in the UIWebView? I noticed another article where this error was a result of using a popover containing a web view without keeping a property to the popover in the controller raising the popover.

Comment: @AnkitSachan Did you manage to fix this issue? I am also facing the same problem in our app.

Answer (score 19):

The following might be the case here

- The user is presented a screen with `UIWebView`
- The `UIViewController` sets `self` as the *delegate* Web page starts downloading
- The User quits screen
- `UIViewController` gets *deallocated* `UIWebView` finishes loading and sends *I am finished loading* message to its *delegate*

or

some other delegate method gets called when the webview object is  no more.i.e dangling pointer effect

1.Always make sure you *stop loading the webView* and *remove the delegate* before *leaving the view*

> Before *releasing an instance of UIWebView* for which you have set a
>   delegate, you must first set its *delegate property to nil*. This can
>   be done,  in your `dealloc` method

Here is the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate)

```
// If ARC is used
- (void)dealloc {
    [_webView setDelegate:nil];
    [_webView stopLoading];
}

// If ARC is not used
- (void)dealloc {
    [webView setDelegate:nil];
    [webView stopLoading];
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

// ARC - Before iOS6 as its deprecated from it.
- (void)viewWillUnload {
    [webView setDelegate:nil];
    [webView stopLoading];
}
```

2.Make sure you are not `stopLoading` and `setDelegate` to nil in `viewWillDisappear`

> if the *ViewController is a child of a another ViewController*, u can
>   trigger the *removal of the ViewController's view* from the *parent
>   ViewController's view* with an animation. At the same time, u can
>   remove the ViewController from its parent and `nil` out its *reference*.
>   at this point `ViewController` will be `nil` and `viewWillDisappear`
>   will *never be called*, meaning the *WebView delegate will never be
>   cleaned up*
>
> Use `dealloc` and ensure that your *WebView is always cleaned up*.

3.Make sure you set the `ContentOffset` of the `subviews` of `webview` to `CGPointZero` without animation

> In iPad in some versions while webview is scrolling if you close the parent
>   viewcontroller without setting ContentOffset to `CGPointZero` this
>   kind of problems will come

so its better to you call the following code of in parent viewcontroller before closing it

```
 for (id subview in webView.subviews){
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]){
            [subview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.Feel free to ask your doubts.

4.Generally speaking You should not *embed* `UIWebView` objects in `UIScrollView` objects. If you do so, *unexpected behavior* can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Here is the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/)

Comment: Generally speaking If you are dealing with memory management problem like EXC_BAD_ACCESS.It is always Good to Enable NSZombies in xcode and check everything and you could try tools like static anaylser...using of these will let you catch the bugs early before user finds out.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying to figure out why my delegate methods never got called and finally know why. I created an instance of my connection class (which inits the streams and the delegate (self)) inside a method and did not store a reference to it. So the GC seems to delete the instance right after the connection is opened and this is why the delegate never got called.

Comment: You are welcome.In iOS there is no GC, ARC does the job..Check if you are conforming to the delegate and make sure you have set delegate instance to self.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling your UIWebView's scrolling behaviour before the ViewController deallocs it

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews){
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]]){
        [subview setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
    }
}
```

p.s. Dipen Chudasama's approach is correct, according to Apple's documentation, you should really set the delegate property to nil before releasing the webview, assuming you have released the webview correctly inside `dealloc` function but not `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score -1):

`UIWebView`s `delegate` uses `assign` and not `weak`. So you need to nullify the `delegate` when the `webView`'s controller gets deallocated.

Example:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
     self.webview.delegate =nil;
}
```

Comment: I did read the complete question. You are saying that you "handle the delegates via…", but did not state that you're also nullifying the web view in `dealloc`.

Comment: Respected @tubtub sir even if I am not doing that in dealloc and somewhere else in the code it should be fine right? though to be precise yes I have handled that in dealloc

Comment: The reason to put this into `dealloc` is to handle cases when your view controller gets deallocated *before* web view delegate are getting called. Could you provide a little sample class of a ViewController where you have a `webView`? This should help us a bit more.

Comment: as I said these are crashlytics bugs and U have of  many webview in my code base these crash logs are not prominently pointing to any particular webviews as its a generic callback

Comment: Yes! I assume you're using the same pattern everywhere a web view is involved. Since this seems to a non trivial issue, Code is necessary to help you more.

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding a web view within your subclass of a web view? Generally that's the problem and if so, changing the superclass to a UIView would solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Chihan, Thanks for the updates but thats not the case I have a view controller thats owning this webview

Answer (score -1):

Use visa versa means first nil your delegate and then after stop loading web view may be help you.

like this.

```
[_webView setDelegate:nil];
[_webView stopLoading];
```

As per apple document : Important Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have set a delegate, you must first set its delegate property to nil.

Answer (score -1):

Use [listener use] instead, to tell your `UIWebView` to handle clicked URL.

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id )listener
{
    [listener use]
}
```

Comment: Devloper app is crashing cause of bad access(i.e celanup of webview and delegate not handled properly)  not because of delegaate method implementation which are anyways optional