# iOS: WebKitLegacy crashes

Tags: ios, crash, webkit

After some relatively safe (as for me) modifications the app began crashing on some WebKitLegacy stuff. I see many crashes in Fabric but can't find stable steps to reproduce.
Does anyone know what can cause those crashes? Please see images attached.

Some app screens use UIWebView to display content - I assume that the problem is somewhere there.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What iOS version are you targeting?  Where are you calling `webview.delegate = nil` and `[webview stopLoading]`?

Comment: I'm targeting iOS7+. Probably next version will be 8+.  
delegate = nil is called in dealloc.  
stopLoading is called in viewWillDisappear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a webkit internal bug (that appeared in iOS 7 but was fixed with iOS 8) where the official solution from Apple will be to  "upgrade to iOS 8."  I'd also try changing wherever you're calling `webview.delegate = nil` and `[webview stopLoading]`, try calling it in `viewWillDisapear` or `dealloc`.

Comment: Stats show 85% iOS 9 and 15% iOS 8 for this error. No iOS 7 at all. The big problem is that I can't reproduce the issue. My only hope is that migration to WKWebView and iOS 8+ will help.

Comment: I am getting this crash in iOS10 as well

Answer (score 2):

UIWebView   EXC_BAD_Address ...Application received signal 
First of All, you should think about  the webView.delegate = nil.
But where ??

My experience:

```
- (void)dealloc{
    /*
     Important
     Before releasing an instance of UIWebView for which you have set a delegate,
     you must first set the UIWebView delegate property to nil before disposing of the UIWebView instance. 
     This can be done, for example, in the dealloc method where you dispose of the UIWebView.
     */
    if (_webView.loading) {
        [self.webView stopLoading];
    }
    _webView.delegate = nil;
}
```

> if the `ViewController` is a child of a another `ViewController`, you can
>   trigger the removal of the `ViewController`'s view from the parent
>   `ViewController`'s view with an animation. At the same time, you can
>   remove the `ViewController` from its parent and nil out its reference.
>   at this point `ViewController` **will be nil** and `viewWillDisappear` **will
>   never be called**, meaning **the WebView delegate will never be cleaned up
>   ** 
>   Use dealloc and ensure that your `WebView` is always cleaned up.

Other excellent linking
[ios:EXC_BAD_ACCESS for Webview delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139034/iosexc-bad-access-for-webview-delegate)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, that signal popped up when a Webview received an update (for example, a response from an embedded image), but it couldn't be rendered because it's not used by the main thread anymore. That means, when the ViewController is not being displayed.

If that's the case, you should be able to reproduce the issue by loading a web page with heavy content (for example, some online newspaper like http://edition.cnn.com/) and dismissing the webview immediately after starting the load, by pushing/popping another ViewController.

How to fix it: indeed, you need to call the methods you mentioned:

```
webview.delegate = nil;
[webview stopLoading];
```

However, the place to do so is on the `viewWillDisappear` method, never on `dealloc`. The reason is simple: `viewWillDisappear` is called on the exact moment where the ViewController is about to lose control of the main thread. However, `dealloc` is called when the VC is about to be released to the heap. This might happen some seconds after, giving the app some precious time to crash, or maybe will never be called at all. Moving both methods there should do the trick.

Comment: Be careful about calling `webview.delegate = nil` in `viewWillDisappear` because if your view controller with a web view pushes any other view controllers, you will lose the delegate when that view controller is popped and the user is back on the web view screen. One approach to fix this could be to re-set `delegate` in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: You're absolutely right :) Thanks for the clarification!