# UIWebview crashes just before complete loading

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

`UIWebView` delegate method crashes on

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType)
```

delegate method just before completion of loading.

```
    thread #1: tid = 0x17c17, 0x000000010f7273ea libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.URLRequest._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSURLRequest>) -> Foundation.URLRequest + 42, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x000000010f7273ea libswiftFoundation.dylib`static Foundation.URLRequest._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC (Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSURLRequest>) -> Foundation.URLRequest + 42
    frame #1: 0x00000001075ade6b StoreFront`@objc SFDocSigningViewController.webView(UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith : URLRequest, navigationType : UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool + 75 at SFDocSigningViewController.swift:0
    frame #2: 0x000000010dbcbf1e UIKit`-[UIWebView webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:] + 280
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139034/iosexc-bad-access-for-webview-delegate

Comment: what is your Url? is http or https?

Comment: The link is 'https'